# Постраничная разбивка for

Tags: php

Как можно разделить следующий массив данных на постраничный вывод без использования бд?

```
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

**UPD:** На странице site.com выводится массив данных (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Как грамотно разделить их на 10 страниц, например site.com/?page=1 выводит 1, site.com?page=2 выводит 2 и так далее.

Comment: более конкретно проблему свою опишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: в таком случае и выводите `$arr[$page-1]`, или что?

Comment: Если вместо `echo $i;` вы выводите запись из бд, то никак, каждый раз - новый запрос.

Comment: я думаю если только всё в куках хранить